# What does the phrase the phrase "soaring through ringed arches" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "soaring through ringed arches" in the following sentence (not available online) from the description of the game Gravity Rider Zero:

> Whether the player is climbing hills or hugging curves or **soaring
> through ringed arches**, a smart camera swoops in to keep her in the
> middle of the action.

Here is a description of the game from Google Play:

> In this bike balancing game, you will be climbing over obstacles,
> discovering new clever mechanics and trials to overcome in each level.
>
> Giant ramps, lasers, spikes, or good old gravity will try to get in
> your way. No sweat though, your vehicle has the perfect speed to pass
> through - with a bit of finesse, you will be fine and not fall off.

Comment: "Soaring" just means "flying," used figuratively to mean jumping. As for "ringed arches," your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: It means *here* what it would mean *anywhere*. It's not a known phrase, just one constructed from words that could be looked up in the dictionary. A 'ringed arch' can only mean an arch, with rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could mean either

- an arch surrounded by/decorated with a ring or rings, as in the phrase "Saturn, the ringed planet".  Possible, but seems unlikely.
- an arch-shaped ring or ring-shaped arch.  An incorrect usage, "ringed" doesn't mean that, but it seems a more likely thing to find in an obstacle course, and careless use of English is quite common in online game blurbs.

Only way for you to tell for sure is to look at the pictures.